# awk split and drop column but something wrong with substr part

Tags: awk

I have an awk code to split a file by columns and print out the output to a new file name.

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1 {h=substr($0, index($0,$5)); next} 
            {file= path ""$1""$2"_"$3"_"$4"_03042017.csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "DM9 03042017" ORS h ORS) substr($0, index($0,$5)) > file} 
             END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}'
```

As I use substr ($0, index($0,$5) so the new output will only have data start at fifth column and the rest. It works fine except when the input data I have got the same value.

For example,

```
product | ID | Branch | Office | Type | ....
ABC     | 12 | KL     |  GH    |  Z   | ....
```

For the above example, the code works well as the data input is different.

```
product | ID | Branch | Office | Type | ....
ABC     | 12 | KK     |  KK    |  Z   | ....
```

But if I have data input like second example, I have the same value data for third and fourth columns, the code doesn't work well. Instead of getting output start and fifth column and more, I got the result at third column and more.

So, I suspect because as the data input for third and fourth are the same, so it stopped at third line as I used substr.

Is anyone can help me on this matter? Sorry for the long post and appreciate it a lot if you guys can give me some ideas. Thank you.

Comment: can you show some more input lines and the expected output?

Comment: Input are something like above with delimiter |

Output, without first 4 columns
`Type | ....`
`Z   | ....`    @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if structure is fixed like your sample (fixed length field)

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' -v path="./" '
   NR==1 {
      for( i=1;i<5;i++) $i = ""
      h = $0; sub(/^[[:blank:]|]+/,"", h)
      next
      }

      {
      file= path $1 $2 "_" $3 "_" $4 "_03042017.csv"

      # remove 4 first field
      for( i=1;i<5;i++) $i = ""
      # cleaning starting space
      Cleaned = $0; sub( /^[[:blank:]|]+/, "", Cleaned)

      print ( a[file]++ ? "" : "DM9 03042017" ORS h ORS ) Cleaned > file
      }

   END {
      for(file in a) { print "EOF " a[file] > file }
      }
   ' YourFile
```

Comment: Script modified by you works but it drop 4 columns header but with 5 columns records. It means header for column dropped successfully but records for columns it dropped extra one column. It supposed to drop 4 entire columns only. May I know you have any ideas to fix this? @NeronLeVelu

Comment: My data is not fixed length field, I didn't notice that earlier. May I know there is anyway to change the length field?  @NeronLeVelu

Comment: i change the script by removing field due to unknow length and not secure match (if many occurence)

Comment: Thanks @NeronLeVelu for being so helpful. Actually what I mean is the data record sometimes for third and fourth columns will be like KK or KLK or GHKL. The length is not just 2. I'm sorry if I have confused you. I have tested the modified code but it doesn't create output at all. I noticed there is an extra / in line 4. Other than that I'm not sure where is the problem.

Comment: adapted for your need 1) include path value as parameter 2) change field separator to include space. Correct the double slash error

Comment: sorry to say it doesn't work out also. I have been trying to fix it but thanks too. I'm still looking how to do it. Actually the first code modified by you looks better but it just dropped extra one column but I don't get it why as we already stated line to be started at $5, so it should just drop 4 columns instead of 5 columns. Thank you. @NeronLeVelu

Comment: `awk -F"|" 'NR==1 {
      for( i=1;i<5;i++) $i = ""
      h = $0; sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"", h)
      next
      } 

      {
      file= path ""$1""$2"_"$3"_"$4"_03042017.csv"

      # remove 4 first field
      for( i=1;i<5;i++) $i = ""
      # cleaning starting space
      Cleaned = $0; sub( /^[[:blank:]]+/, "", Cleaned)

      print ( a[file]++ ? "" : "DM9 03042017" ORS h ORS ) Cleaned > file
      }

   END {
      for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file
      } ' file`    

This code works but I can keep the delimiter "|" ? Appreciate your help. @NeronLeVelu

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I got it already. Thanks man :) @NeronLeVelu